# Functional programming(Streams) return type ArrayList java

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

I have one List and another ArrayList. I want to distinct each of them and to return new ArrayList.

```
String[] input = scn.nextLine().split("\\s");
ArrayList<String> result = Arrays.stream(input).filter(a -> a.length() > 10).distinct()
```

I want to return ArrayList. I have no problems with returning List (Collectors.asList etc....)

Regards

Answer (score 3):

You should collect the result via `collect` method:

```
ArrayList<String> result = Arrays.stream(input)
                                 .filter(a -> a.length() > 10)
                                 .distinct()
                                 .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

If you don't care about particular `List` implementation, it's preferred to use `toList()` collector:

```
List<String> result = Arrays.stream(input)
                            .filter(a -> a.length() > 10)
                            .distinct()
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Sorry for duplicate!

Answer (score 0):

Collect as a List and then make a new ArrayList from said List.